# Nexus Repository: Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins ...

Tags: maven, nexus

Hi I have downloaded and installed an allmost clean nexus server (just removed the public access). Then I have changed my maven settings.xml like this

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>xx</id>
            <name>xx</name>
            <url>http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>thirdparty</id>
            <username>xxx</username>
            <password>xxx</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>releases</id>
            <username>xxx</username>
            <password>xxx</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <username>xxx</username>
            <password>xxx</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>central</id>
            <username>xxx</username>
            <password>xxx</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

.. where host and users are obfuscated :-)

Finally I deleted everything in .m2/repository/* and typed the following:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=home.my.scratch -DartifactId=HelloWorld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

This will give me a cupple of "[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:" errors but in the .m2/repository directory there are some files and folders again. So the host and access should be working correctly.

Here is the exact stack:

```
C:\tmp\lala>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=home.my.scratch -DartifactId=HelloWorld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
Bad level value for property: .level
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could
 not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its dependencies c
ould not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could n
ot be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not b
e resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.0
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could n
ot be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its de
pendencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies
 could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could
 not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to mindbusters (http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/): Not authorized, Reason
Phrase:Unauthorized.
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to mindbusters (http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:
Unauthorized.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/ was cached in the local repository, resolution w
ill not be reattempted until the update interval of mindbusters has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from
/to mindbusters (http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not
 be reattempted until the update interval of mindbusters has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to mindbuster
s (http://some.host:8081/nexus/content/groups/allrepos/): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins .........

Your nexus repository is not configured for retrieving plugins from maven central. when you specify `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` , it expects to find the plugins inside its storage. So, when you install a clean nexus server, it starts searching for descriptors for maven plugins within nexus itself, whereas they are to located at maven central.

To solve this, you will have to define the plugin repository to re-route all requests to retrieve maven plugins to `maven central`.

To do this, edit your settings.xml and add the following code snippet in your `profiles`.

```
....
<pluginRepository>
    <id>central</id>
    <!-- This can be any URL -->
    <!-- even something like 'http://central/' will work fine -->
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
....
```

**Edit**

The URL entry can be any bogus URL ( it doesn't have to be any valid URL ) since it will always re-route via nexus when mirror settings are defined as `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`

```
....
<pluginRepository>
 <id>central</id>
 <url>http://central/</url>
 <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
</releases>
<snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
</snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
....
```

Comment: This is the wrong way of doing it since you are again hitting Central directly rather than via Nexus and taking advantage of the caching in Nexus. The correct way is documented in the Nexus book at http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

Comment: @ManfredMoser Won't that URL (one which I wrote) also get overridden by the mirror defined in the same settings.xml ? AFAIK, if you specify `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` it will re-route any request via nexus regardless of any URL specified in the repositories.

Comment: Yes it will. Which is why it is misleading to have a valid url in there. The other thing you are missing it so to have a repository entry as well that allows snapshots.

Comment: I see. I'll update my answer and place a bogus url there so that its useful for others.